# What are the known classes of undirected graphs such that every graph belonging to that class is guaranteed to have a Hamiltonian Path?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-paths, graph-classes

One trivial class of graphs is the class consisting of complete graphs or complete bipartite graphs with equal sized partitions.
I would love to know if more such classes exist.

Comment: The wikipedia article for Hamiltonian path gives some sufficient conditions (mainly the Bondy–Chvátal theorem and special cases as well as the fact that any 4-connected planar graph has a Hamiltonian path).

Comment: I checked the wiki article. The question intends to know about more such classes which have this property.

Comment: It's a (fairly) well-known open question as to whether every Cayley graph is Hamiltonian. [Pak & Radoicic 2008](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/hamcayley9.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

A good resource to answer questions like this is graphclasses.org.  You find the graph class you care about -- in this case, [Hamiltonian graphs](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1092.html).  Then check the maximal subclasses section, and possibly forward-search from there.

Comment: Thanks. That was quite helpful tip.

Comment: All but one of these classes explicitly includes Hamiltonicity in their definition.